# How to remove flickering green lines on screen?

Tags: 10.10, hardware, graphics, display, hp

I've been using Ubuntu 10.10 on my HP Pavilion dv4-1430us Notebook. For some time now, I've been getting these thin green flickering lines at the bottom of my screen. And I've no clue as to what's causing this problem: hardware, battery or graphics card. I even tried "nomodeset" as suggested in some forums, but it wasn't of any help. I'm looking for a way to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds *very much* like a failing connections on the display, rather than a problem with Ubuntu. If you want to make sure, try to replicate the problem when Ubuntu is not booted (e.g. in the BIOS screen).

[image]
*this sort of thing*

I don't suggest you open up your laptop, but repair at a local computer store will probably be *reasonably cheap*. If you can confirm the problem *is* related to the hardware, talk to a few local repair places to see if they can do anything about it. And just as a small tip: bring your computer, they'll have a much easier time figuring out what it is then.

I Hope I'm wrong (but I don't think I am).

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I'll try consulting my local repair shops. In case you realize it could be due to some other issue also, plz let me know.